# AES Wrap function

Tags: c, cryptography, aes

This code is supposed to implement [RFC 3394](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3394) which also described in [this](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-38F.pdf) PDF at page 11.

Are there any weak places or formatting issues in attached source? Or maybe some places are not explicit enough?

```
void wrap(  const unsigned char *key, const unsigned char *plaintext, unsigned int plaintext_length,
            unsigned char *ciphertext, unsigned int *ciphertext_length, unsigned int semiblocksize)
{
    int i, j, k;
    unsigned int n, t, tt;
    unsigned char *A, B[16], *R;

    int targetlevel = 0, p = semiblocksize;
    while (p >>= 1) ++targetlevel;

    n = plaintext_length >> targetlevel;

    A = B;

    memset(A, 0xa6, semiblocksize);

    memcpy(ciphertext+semiblocksize, plaintext, plaintext_length);

    for(j=0, t=1; j<=5; j++)
    {
        for(i=1, R=ciphertext+semiblocksize; i<=n; i++, t++, R+=semiblocksize)
        {
            memcpy(B+semiblocksize, R, semiblocksize);

            AES128_ECB_encrypt(B, key, B);
               
            for(k=semiblocksize - 1, tt=t; (k>=0) && (tt>0); k--, tt>>=semiblocksize)
            {
                A[k] ^= (unsigned char) (tt & 0xFF);
            }
            memcpy(R, B+semiblocksize, semiblocksize);
        }
    }
    memcpy(ciphertext, A, semiblocksize);
    *ciphertext_length = plaintext_length + semiblocksize;
}
```

I know, that ECB mode should not be used in production, but this is only for ensuring output correctness by checking coincidence with the RFC.

Answer (score 1):

1. Arrays are best indexed with type `size_t` rather than `unsigned`.  Notice unnecessary mixed `int/unsigned` types in `i<=n`.  Both should be `size_t`.
2. Avoid naked magic numbers.  Why `16` in `unsigned char B[16]`?
3. Formatting:  For review purposes, consider limiting to the width to the target display.

   ```
   // void wrap(  const unsigned char *key, const unsigned char *plaintext, unsigned int plaintext_length,
   // unsigned char *ciphertext, unsigned int *ciphertext_length, unsigned int semiblocksize)

   void wrap(const unsigned char *key, const unsigned char *plaintext, 
       unsigned int plaintext_length, unsigned char *ciphertext, 
       unsigned int *ciphertext_length, unsigned int semiblocksize)
   ```
4. See little value in the vertical line spacing.  Removing a few of these blank line to group common elements together would make more sense.

   ```
   unsigned char *A, B[16], *R;

   int targetlevel = 0, p = semiblocksize;
   while (p >>= 1) ++targetlevel;

   n = plaintext_length >> targetlevel;

   A = B;

   memset(A, 0xa6, semiblocksize);

   memcpy(ciphertext+semiblocksize, plaintext, plaintext_length);

   for(j=0, t=1; j<=5; j++)
   ```
5. `for()` loops are best coded with `for (i=first_value; i<some_N; i += delta)`.   Complex usage of `for()` loops tend to be code golfing.  Indexing from `0` is idiomatic in C and should be followed when reasonable.  Following this helps convey meaning and avoids off-by-1 errors.

   ```
   // for(j=0, t=1; j<=5; j++) {
     // for(i=1, R=ciphertext+semiblocksize; i<=n; i++, t++, R+=semiblocksize)

   t = 0;  
   for(j=0; j<6; j++) {
     R = ciphertext;
     for(i=0; i<n; i++) { 
       R += semiblocksize;
       t++;
       ...
     }
   }
   ```
6. Variable names `A`, `B` convey little meaning unless standard for the encryption algorithm's notation.
7. Cast serves no purpose here in C

   ```
    //  A[k] ^= (unsigned char) (tt & 0xFF);
    A[k] ^= tt & 0xFF;
   ```